# How to change string depending on checkedlistbox

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, checkedlistbox

Pretty self explanatory. I would like to change a string if a certain option is checked in the checkedListBox. And change it again when a different option is checked. I'd say that a if statement would work but how would I do that inside a if statement so that other objects can use that string?

Comment: Can you post code that you have to do this?  Or do you need help getting started?

Comment: Monitor the [CheckedListBox.ItemCheck Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could make the string a constant and assign a value to it in the checkedListBox's SelectedIndexChanged event. Something like (pseudocode):

```
private readonly String clbResponse = String.Empty;
. . .
protected void clb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, eventargs e)
{
    int indexSelected = clb.SelectedIndex;
    case (indexSelected)
    0:
     clbResponse = "index 0 was selected";
     break;
    1: 
     clbResponse = "index 0 was selected";
     break;
    . . .
    default
       break;
}
```